# How to add one day to today's date?

Tags: python, date

I wrote this line of code:

```
date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

How can I add one day to today's date?

Comment: Start by not formatting the time to a string. Do you need to have tomorrow's date as a string? What is this going to be used for?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm actually going to strip this string to days, months and years.

Comment: That doesn't mean much. You mean you need to have the day, month and year values as integers?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes.

Comment: Then you are using the wrong library, use the [`datetime` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using `datetime`. Then you could do

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow_formatted = tomorrow.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(tomorrow_formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` and `timedelta` are not the only 'right' libraries.

**`arrow`** is nice too!

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.now().replace(days=+1).format('DD/MM/YY')
'22/05/17'
```

Other attractive features to recommend it as well.

Comment: except arrow is not in the standard lib. KISS: refrain from adding extra libs unless necessary (in this case, it's quite easy to do with existing `datetime`)

Comment: @cowbert: There's no *necessity* of using arrow, I agree. But dates and times are not generally easy. It's worth being aware of other possibilities.